# Task blocks UI thread with .dll method

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, task, multitasking

I've created app for exporting data into Excel. Time for creating Excel file takes about 10 minutes, so I've decided to do that in another thread without blocking UI thread, so that users can continue working with app. I have a .dll for exporting data, and I've done same thing many times in Winforms with no problems at all. My .dll file takes cancellation token as a parameter, so user can cancel export any time, that is why I prefer working with this .dll.

Unfortunally I'm very new to WPF, so I can't figure out how to create same thing as in Winforms. Here is my code snippet:

```
public CancellationTokenSource cancel_task = new CancellationTokenSource();  

private async void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            //Doing some work in UI thread before calling Task.Run …

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
               Export_to_Excel(dict_queries, dtp.Value);
            }, cancel_task.Token);
}

void Export_to_Excel(Dictionary<string, int> queries, DateTime? date)
{
    try
    {
       using (var con = new OracleConnection(conn_string))
       {
         con.Open();

         //Fetching DB Command to start with exporting data ...

         //Inicializing my .dll method, added as reference to project   
         var export_xlsx = new Excel_export();

         //Here is where It starts to block UI thread
         Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { export_xlsx.Export_command(cmd_export,cancel_task.Token);});
       } 
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
          MessageBox.Show (ex.Message);
     }
 }
```

If I use only this line  `export_xlsx.Export_command(cmd_export,cancel_task.Token);`
 instead of `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke...`, then I get "**System.Threading.ThreadStateException: Current Thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made...**" error. This looks to me like a .dll is back on UI Thread, even If It was called from non-UI Thread...However this line perfectly works for me in Winforms, so I don't know what Is wrong here.

I tried many different variations of **Task.Run** or **Task.Factory.StartNew** (as I normally do in Winforms), but everything leads me to blocking UI thread or different kind of errors.

My design Is Main Window with Frame, and inside that Frame I open a Page where I click on button to export data. As said, I'm a newbie in WPF, so maybe this is causing my problems. Any suggestions kindly appreciated !

**EDIT:**

I think I figured out what is wrong. In my .dll code I call SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog(), which Is -- as I know -- a UI thread operation. Unfortunally I need It in this app, Is there anything I can do in this case ?

I'm guessing this is why everything works fine in Winforms, because I don't use  SaveFileDialog there.

Comment: Have you tried starting a thread (not task) and setting the [`Thread.ApartmentState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.apartmentstate) property to the value `ApartmentState.STA` using the method [`Thread.SetApartmentState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.setapartmentstate)?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I tried but I can't figure where to put that in code. A little guidance maybe?

Comment: Inside the `Button1_Click` handler instead of starting a task with `await Task.Run`, create and start a new thread that runs the `Export_to_Excel` method. And set the `ApartmentState` of the thread before starting it.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, I receive same error as with posted solution of Erwin, onl y this time It's showing me error when I call method **Export_to_Excel**.

Comment: Can you stick a `ConfigureAwait(false)` after that `Task.Run()` and see if anything changes?

Comment: @TanveerBadar please take a look at my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According your code you are falling into both errors at the same time:

1. You are trying to use OLE in a non STA thread
2. You are trying to access a DispatcherObject (SaveFileDialog) from another thread

Why your original code works (but blocks the UI)? Because you are dispatching the OLE work to the UI thread wich is STA and from the UI thread you can access to SaveFileDialog without problem.

About "The calling thread cannot access this object..." error:

`Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke` will delegate the work to the UI tread so in your code you are creating a thread to just make the UI work again; this is why you are blocking the UI. Use Invoke to just update UI elements (or any DispatcherObject) from another thread not for all the work. If you try to access a DispatcherObject (like UI controls) from another thread without Invoke you get "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns It" error.

Now about the "Current Thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA)..." error:

Try to set the apartment state of the new thread your are creating and use Invoke on SaveFileDialog:

```
    public static Task<bool> StartSTATask(Action func) {
      var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
      Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
      {
        try {
          func();
          tcs.SetResult(true);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
          tcs.SetException(e);
        }
      });
      thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
      thread.Start();
      return tcs.Task;
    }

public CancellationTokenSource cancel_task = new CancellationTokenSource();  

private async void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            //Doing some work in UI thread before calling Task.Run …
          try{
            await StartSTATask(() => { Export_to_Excel(dict_queries, dtp.Value);});
           }
          catch(Exception ex){
              MessageBox.Show (ex.Message); //lets keep UI things in UI thread
          }

}

void Export_to_Excel(Dictionary<string, int> queries, DateTime? date)
{

       using (var con = new OracleConnection(conn_string))
       {
         con.Open();

         //Fetching DB Command to start with exporting data ...

         //Inicializing my .dll method, added as reference to project   
         var export_xlsx = new Excel_export();

         export_xlsx.Export_command(cmd_export,cancel_task.Token);
       } 
     }  
 }

//into dll

public void Export_command(cmd_export,cancel_task.Token){
  //do work
  Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke( () => SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog());
}
```

Comment: @jvaquero, link you provided doesn't work for me, I receiver errors once I change the application’s build action. About code you posted - how cam I use that and where, a little too complex for my knowledge ?

Comment: more or less like this

Comment: please take a look at my EDIT.

Comment: @Lucy82  Should I assume that you can not change the .dll? Because if you can change it you can apply the first part of my answer; calling Invoke( ()=> SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog()) should work....

Comment: Invoke( ()=> SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog()) doesn't work in my .dll. I figured a way to show dialog in UI but code get's very messy. Haven't tried your full example though, will let you know about that.

Comment: I tried your example and It works for me. I ended up with slightly different solution, but many thanks for all your effort !

Answer (score 0):

This is could be a work around for your problem :

```
   Excel_export export_xlsx;
private async void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        //Doing some work in UI thread before calling Task.Run …

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
           export_xlsx = new Excel_export();
           Export_to_Excel(dict_queries, dtp.Value);
        }, cancel_task.Token);
}

void Export_to_Excel(Dictionary<string, int> queries, DateTime? date)
{
try
{
   using (var con = new OracleConnection(conn_string))
   {
     con.Open();

     //Fetching DB Command to start with exporting data ...

     //Here is where It starts to block UI 
      export_xlsx.Export_command(cmd_export,cancel_task.Token);
   } 
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
      MessageBox.Show (ex.Message);
 }
```

}

Comment: that leads me to "**The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns It**" error, in line **Task.Run**.

Comment: this is weird, try with Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { export_xlsx.Export_command(cmd_export,cancel_task.Token);}); see if the UI is still responsive

Comment: no I still receive same error. IS there something wrong with my App.xaml maybe ? I've changed It a bit, I have no Main() method inside .cs.

Comment: please take a look at my EDIT.